# Can excessive text messages stored on phone cause issues?

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, t-mobile

Can too many text messages stored on my phone prevent me from receiving new messages?

Recently I've had multiple people text me, yet I haven't received the messages. I checked the messaging log on my cell account online, and the incoming messages are listed, yet they never showed up on my device.

I spoke with T-Mobile tech support; he said that I had too many messages on my phone (5000+), and that the more text messages I have stored on my device, the higher the chance of an incoming message getting corrupted (that is, not received). He recommended keeping only ~200 messages on my phone.

Is that good advice?

He also said to restart my phone every night, which I'll start doing (instead of every few days), but I had never heard to not store too many messages, so I was curious if there is a technical basis for his advice...

I have an HTC One S (Android 4.1.1), and I am using the stock messaging app on T-Mobile (in the US).

Comment: Yes, either because you're running out of space or because the app is poorly optimized (a LOT of SMS apps are very bad about this).

Comment: @MatthewRead Regarding the unoptimized app possibility, is there a 3rd party SMS/MMS messaging app you would suggest that *is* optimized? Not looking for anything fancy, just reliability...

Comment: I am not a big texter, but [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) gets a lot of recommendations here.  There's also [Google Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging).

Comment: Handcent is amazing.  I've been using it for years, and wouldn't go back to any other one.  It can be fitful at times, but I have no issues storing large amounts of texts.